# Rest Assured - body() in given() or when()

Tags: java, rest-assured

What differences putting .body() in given() or when()?
I tried both and they works the same.

The documentation on rest-assured git page says .body() is inserted in given(), and I tried searching for any article on putting .body() in when(), but found nothing. I asked because the team I'm working with is using body() in when().

Code Example:

```
// #1  
given().headers("Content-Type", "application/json").body(classBody).
when().post(urlAPI).
then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response()

// #2
given().headers("Content-Type", "application/json").
when().body(classBody).post(urlAPI).
then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response()
```

Both codes return the same result.
So, which one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the java docs you will notice that when() is a syntactic sugar.
So basically it will only affect the look of your code, you could skip when() and it will work.

I prefer to use example #1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Given and When work as the same
2. They used to make the test more readable. So, depend on your purpose you can use them interchangeable

Answer (score -1):

This is the best way to write the code. `Given()`, `when()` is used to make the code more readable and understandable. That are called as syntactic sugar.

```
given().headers("Content-Type", "application/json").body(classBody).when().post(urlAPI)
.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response()
```